# Output new line instead of \r\n

Tags: php

I am using this method to store data in database:

```
$content = $_POST['content'];
$content = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$content);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO na_posts(postuid,content) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$post_id,$content);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

And I use this code to get data from the database:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM na_posts WHERE postuid = '" . $id . "'";
$stmt = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $stmt->fetch_Object();
echo nl2br($row->content);
```

but the output is like this:

**hey this is line one \r\n this is line two**

Why are the new lines show up like this `\r\n`?

It works if I remove the call to `mysqli_real_escape_string()` which is important for security as i have read.

Comment: your double escaping `$content` with `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `bind_param()` which is the same as not escaping at all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mysqli_real_escape_string` is not needed if you're using bind parameters, as you are here with `bind_param`. It's one or the other, you don't need both. Bind parameters are better for various reasons, mainly that it's easier to build the SQL and the database can also be more efficient (since it can be more efficient at executing the same query twice even if the bound values vary).

For outputting the value, in HTML you should use something like `htmlspecialchars` as mentioned by Alamri. Most decent templating engines will allow you to escape values by default so that you don't have to remember to escape every time. [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) for example will escape values by default in its templates (other PHP web frameworks are available).

Comment: Thank you very much... what about the output method i use, is it secure ?

Comment: @Alamri you should run your output through `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent XSS: `echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row->content));`

Comment: @MrCode Thank you, it's all about XSS, i faced it before, now i have to be more careful, many thanks..

Comment: Agree with MrCode (assuming you're outputting an HTML page) - if you're doing any amount of HTML output, it's better to use a templating engine that escapes by default so that it's less effort to stay protected.